# For Loop counting last even when skipped

Tags: java

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        Token t;
        StringBuilder sb;
        if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            sb = new StringBuilder().append(c);
            for (int j = i + 1; j < s.length(); j++) {
                if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(j))) {
                    sb.append(s.charAt(j));

                } else {
                    i = j-1;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Essentially it needs to go through a string, and pull out numbers.  Numbers with multiple digits need to stay together.  It does this right for the most part, but if a multi-digit number is at the end, it copies the final digit into a new token. (Tokens store data as strings, this code goes on to check for letters and variables too.)

I figure it's a problem with my "else" logic, but not sure how I should do that.

Thanks

Edit:  Sample input: 4+j+55
Output:
4
+
J
+
55
5 <----the thing i want to stop

Comment: Can we see some sample input and desired output?

Comment: Done, sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this example string "12", in the first iteration of the outer loop it'll do:

- check that '1' is a digit and run the inner loop
- the inner loop will append '2'
- the inner loop will exit due to reaching the end of the string (but not adjust the value of `i`)
- the outer loop will increment `i` and look at the digit '2'

The inner loop needs to detect the "end of string" case and set `i` accordingly

Comment: ...That's what I'm doing wrong.  I don't need the else statement to handle the iteration, I just need to do i++ if the inner loop appends.  Thanks!